# Swift 3 - How do I pass down unique information for each Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.

Hello, I am going to try to explain fully what I am trying to do and what I've done in the hopes that someone can help me flesh out my issues.

Here is my storyboard.

[image]

It is the first tab of a tab bar controller.  It consists of a table view controller (let's call it Table 1) whose cells when clicked, will show another table view controller (Table 2) with unique information.  As an example, say Table 1 has cells that titled "Fruits," "Vegetables," "Proteins" and when clicking on "Fruits," Table 2 shows with "Apple," "Orange," "Pear."

So my first question is: does my Storyboard set up accurately capture the behavior that I want Table 2 cells to be unique depending on what is clicked in Table 1?  Or is that Table 2 cells will be all the same?

Moving on: I have already successfully generated the content on Table 1 but the unique content on Table 2 is giving me trouble.

Table 2 content is generated on another tab of the Tab Bar Controller and I need it pass it into that view first.

So, in the other tab, I am trying to do something like this.  Basically, trying to access Table 2 and set fields in there too be populated.

```
let table2VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "table2VC") as! Table2VC
table2VC.unique_title_label = UILabel()
table2VC.unique_title_label.text = "Some unique text"
```

In Table 2 VC

```
var unique_title_label : UILabel!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ... 
    table2cell.titleLabel = unique_title_label
    table2cell.mytvc = self
    return table2cell
}
```

And in Table2Cell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!
```

And I've linked the outlet to the corresponding Table 2 label.  However, when running this, no unique labels are being populated.  It simply says "Label" as the Storyboard has it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you wish to pass data between two `UITableViewControllers`. First, you need to think about you `data structure`, it means that you need data to present in the first tableView, and also data to present in the second tableView of course. 
Since the second tableView is waiting on the first one to get populated. So your dataStructure is very important.

For example some thing like:

```
struct personInfo {
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    var detailInfos:[String]
}
```

So in the first TableView, as you know every would contains their own data which mean in this current example each row would have a `firstname`, a `lastname` and also `detailInfos`.

Since you are using tableView, you could either use `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` or `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` don't use both since prepare gets called before the `didSelectRowAt` which will give you a weird behavior.

There is my full example to you:

```
struct personInfo {
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    var detailInfos:[String]
}

enum segueIdentifier:String {
    case first_id = "passDataViaSegue"
}

class FirstTableView: UITableViewController {

    var personInfos:[personInfo]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        personInfos  = [ personInfo(firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Doe", detailInfos: [
                "we need this datat","we are here my man","I am not amateur"
            ])
        ]
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int {
        return personInfos.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = personInfos[indexPath.row].firstName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = personInfos[indexPath.row].lastName
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier.first_id.rawValue {
            let destination = segue.destination as! SecondTableView
            guard  let row  = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                return
            }
            destination.detailArr = personInfos[row].detailInfos
        }
    }

}

class SecondTableView: UITableViewController {

    var detailArr:[String]?

    var _details = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let details = detailArr else { return }
        _details = details
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int {
        return _details.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = _details[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

In this example, I have use the same setup as yours, just with different data, and default `TableViewCell`.